# FUEL CMS admin gives error 404

Tags: fuelcms

I installed Fuel CMS to ubuntu server, but cannot open the FUEL admin. When I open the http:// (my ip)/fuel/, Welcome to Fuel CMS Version 1.2.1 "Getting started" page shows just fine. I have also installed the database. http:// (my ip)/phpmyadmin works (phpmyadmin is on /var/lib/). However, http:// (my ip)/fuel/ redirects to http:// (my ip)/fuel/start, and gives 404 error.

I have tried to edit .htaccess and apache configuration files with no luck, and restarted apache multiple times, so now I'm out of ideas.

I'm going to list information about my configuration below. Is there something I'm missing, or What else could be a problem?

My apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Mod rewrite is on. At least, when I try to enable it, it says so: Module rewrite already enabled

The tree for fuel installation is this:

```
/var/
| -- www
|  | -- html
|  |   | -- assets
|  |   |    |-- cache
|  |   |    |-- css
|  |   |    |-- docs
|  |   |    |-- images
|  |   |    |-- js
|  |   |    |-- pdf
|  |   |    |-- swf
|  |   | -- fuel
|  |   |    |-- application
|  |   |    |-- codeigniter
|  |   |    |-- data_backup
|  |   |    |-- install
|  |   |    |-- licenses
|  |   |    |-- modules
|  |   |    |-- scripts
```

My htaccess (from /var/www/html) looks like this  (I have also tried RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [L]) with no luck:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /html/

        <Files .*>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny From All
        </Files>

        # Allow asset folders through
        RewriteRule ^(fuel/modules/(.+)?/assets/(.+)) - [L]

        # Protect application and system files from being viewed
        RewriteRule     ^(fuel/install/.+|fuel/crons/.+|fuel/data_backup/.+|fuel/codeigniter/.+|fuel/modules/.+|fuel/application/.+) - [F,L]


        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]

        # Prevents access to dot files (.git, .htaccess) - security.
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.

- Open your root .htaccess
- go to line 5 and change the value of RewriteBase to / 
  it should look like this

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

Answer (score 1):

In fuel/application/config/MY_fuel.php, is `$config['admmin_enabled']` set to `TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a fresh install of apache2 on Windows.  My phpinfo said mod_rewrite was enable but I found that not all of my httpd.conf were set right for mod_rewrite.

I followed the steps on http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting/ and it fixed my problem.